# Please help me In VF Page by using standardcontroller I wrote some programme

Tags: visualforce

[image: [<apex:inputFile value=" {!Account.AnnualRevenue}"/> ] with this i got error i didnot understand the meaning..]
[image: By removing this [<apex:inputFile value=" {!Account.AnnualRevenue}"/> ] I got result all choose file option got like this below Image what is the wrong in this I would like to know.]

Please Explain as early as possible

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You need to use words to describe the issue, and provide plenty of detail. Read [ask] and [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Please also [edit] this post to provide your code and markup as _text_, not images.

Answer (score 2):

You meant to use `apex:inputField`, not `apex:inputFile`. The latter is used to upload a file, which must be bound to a Blob data type, while the former is meant to be used to input a field value dynamically (e.g. picklist vs text).

Comment: thank u where i had done mistake i understood